# Checked items on listbox with 2 columns to be moved on top of the list

Tags: vba, listbox

I have an MultiSelect Listbox with 2 columns and 100 items. It is possible that the selected items to go on top of the listbox?

For example, this is the listbox:

```
Azerty      120ms
QWERTY      12,56ms
RAW         450,25ms
doWn        235,00 ms
alfa        258,7ms
etc....
```

If I check 'doWn and RAW' to go on top of the list like this (the order is not important):

```
doWn        235,00 ms
RAW         450,25ms
Azerty      120ms
QWERTY      12,56ms
alfa        258,7ms
etc....
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done it like this.
The code is in a textbox change status.
Add Items of listBox in an array.
Loop through list box to see which item is selected.
Add selection numbers in a string, Strings in an array of selected_items and not_selected_items.
Loop array to rearrange the items based on selection and original array

code:

```
Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
 
    Dim arr()
    Dim arrYes() As String
    Dim arrNo() As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim yes As String, no As String
    
    On Error GoTo nirvana
    arr = Me.ListBox2.List
    

    For i = 0 To Me.ListBox2.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListBox2.selected(i) = True Then
            yes = i & "," & yes
        Else
            no = i & "," & no
        End If
    Next
    
    arrYes = Split(StrReverse(Left(yes, Len(yes) - 1)), ",")
    arrNo = Split(StrReverse(Left(no, Len(no) - 1)), ",")
    
    i = -1
    For j = 0 To UBound(arrYes())
        i = i + 1
        With Me.ListBox2
            .List(i, 0) = arr(arrYes(j), 0)
            .List(i, 1) = arr(arrYes(j), 1)
            .selected(i) = True
        End With
    Next j
    
    For j = 0 To UBound(arrNo())
        i = i + 1
        With Me.ListBox2
            .List(i, 0) = arr(arrNo(j), 0)
            .List(i, 1) = arr(arrNo(j), 1)
            .selected(i) = False
        End With
    Next j
nirvana:
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```